# Catch in Angularfire2 v5 error

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire5

I am converting the use of Firebase Storage to use the Angularfire2 library (currently v5.0.0-rc.5-next) which means I am now using observables rather than promises.

How can I catch error such as `storage/object-not-found` and react accordingly?

This is currently my code but I cannot add a `catch` to it as some examples I found.

```
const avatarRef =  this.afStorage.ref('${userId}/avatar/${this.avatarThumbnail}${user.avatar}');

avatarRef.getDownloadURL()
    .take(1)
    .subscribe((avatarUrl) => {
        resolve(avatarUrl);
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At its most basic, observers take an error callback to receive any unhandled errors in an observable stream. `getDownloadURL()` returns Observable that is why you need to subscribe. If you get an error (file not found or other) you will invoke code from error callback only.

```
avatarRef.getDownloadURL()
.take(1)
.subscribe((avatarUrl) => {
    // Do something with avatarUrl here
   console.log(avatarUrl);
}, (error) => {
   // Handle error here
   // Show popup with errors or just console.error
   console.error(error);
});
```

Also I suggest you to read articles about error handling using RxJS and difference between Observable and Promise: [link1](https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/error_handling.html), [link2](https://alligator.io/rxjs/simple-error-handling/)

Answer (score 0):

The following solution work for me

```html
startUpload(file) {

    // The storage path
    const path = `image${new Date().getTime()}.jpg`;

    // Reference to storage bucket
    const ref = this.storage.ref(path);
    let image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + file;
    // The main task
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const upload = ref.putString(image, 'data_url');
      const sub = upload.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        finalize(async () => {
          try {
            const photoURL = await ref.getDownloadURL().toPromise();
            this.message.senderUid = this.currentUser.uid;
            this.message.receiverUid = this.selectedUser.uid;
            this.message.text = this.inputText && this.inputText !== '' ? this.inputText : 'File';
            this.message.senderName = this.currentUser.name;
            this.message.chatId = this.chatId;
            this.message.file = photoURL;
            this.firebaseService.insertMessage(this.message)
              .then(() => {
                this.inputText = '';
                this.message.file = null;
                this.scrollToBottomOnInit();
              });

            resolve({photoURL})
          } catch (err) {
            this.inputText = '';
            this.message.file = null;
            reject(err)
          }
          sub.unsubscribe()
        })
      ).subscribe((data) => {
        console.log('storage: ', data)
      })
    })
  }
```

Source: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1736#issuecomment-515798352

Comment: Can you please add some details as to how this solution works and why it is a good solution. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: it wait until the upload is finish and processing